# Asynchronous comunications with websockets

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm using a service for voice recognition that accepts audio snippets and returns a text transcription. The service is used asynchronously, that is, while it receives audio data it answers partial text recognition, up to that point

[image]

Just using a simple infinite send_audio>wait_response locks up the program as it waits for an answer that the service doesn't send.
So I tried to use [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io), with coroutines to separate the send and receive parts of the code. But I'm not having much sucess either.

```
async def getMessages(ws):
    while 1:
        rcv = await ws.recv()
        ...


async def sendMessages(ws):
    while 1:
        await ws.send("CREATE_SESSION")
        ...

async def main():
    async with websockets.connect(ADDR) as websocket:
        sender = asyncio.create_task(sendMessages(websocket))
        getter = asyncio.create_task(getMessages(websocket))

        await asyncio.wait([sender, getter])

asyncio.run(main())
```

Is there any better way to do this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Edit the question to explain "not having much success". What happens, what exactly should happen?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using python
I would recommend using [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

if you deployed it to heroku too,  you would get fast results

Cisco and many others use it

[image: Django — the request/response cycle]

Comment: django-channels is a server, I'm writing a client application, to deploy a whole asgi server to run django and all its dependencies on the client is not viable.

Comment: Well in that case, you don't have install and setup all of these dependencies.
I don't know what is the nature of your App. I don't code much using asyncio.
If I were you I would run the websocket localy forever =>
wait asyncio.Future()  # run forever#
and play with messages status variable maybe.
probably this is not the best solution for you
I wish I have some time to test the code myself.

I thought you are working on the back-end.
Good luck and have a nice day, Mate

Answer (score 0):

This example just prints TEXT or VOICE on a timer. It works fine with either time delay slower (i.e. server sends more messages or client sends more messages) however there is an extra delay than the sleep time provides that I'm unclear on.

#### server

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import time

async def consumer_handler(websocket):
    tstart = time.perf_counter()
    async for message in websocket:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"{time.perf_counter() - tstart:0.2f} server got {message}")

async def producer_handler(websocket):
    while True:
        await websocket.send('TEXT')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def handler(websocket):
    await asyncio.gather(
        consumer_handler(websocket),
        producer_handler(websocket),
    )

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 8765):
        await asyncio.Future()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

#### client

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import time

async def consumer_handler(websocket):
    tstart = time.perf_counter()
    async for message in websocket:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"{time.perf_counter() - tstart:0.2f} client got {message}")

async def producer_handler(websocket):
    while True:
        await websocket.send('VOICE')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

async def client(websocket):
    await asyncio.gather(
        consumer_handler(websocket),
        producer_handler(websocket),
    )

async def main():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:
        await client(websocket)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```